# kNN algorithm on apple stock

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to create a kNN algorithm for stock prediction, with at least 80% correct predictions on the test data. I have a problem with the StandardScaler from sklearn. For some reason it says that there is a "typo" in the word "Scaler", which I find is weird. Does someone know how to solve this issue? If you find more mistakes in the code, please tell me how to fix them, but I think it should be mostly correct (some might be wrong). I want the polynomial line to show around a week in the future. I use data from a private API Key from Marketstack.com, which is provided in JSON formatting. The data contains of EOD data (end of day) with a limit of 1000 days in Descending order.

```
# Exports API data to a csv file on my hardware and then I import the csv data after it's sorted
df.to_csv('Test_Sample.csv', index=False)
dataframe = pd.read_csv('Test_Sample.csv')
dataframe['symbol']=dataframe['symbol'].astype(float)
dataframe['exchange']=dataframe['exchange'].astype(float)
dataframe['date']=dataframe['date'].astype(float)
dataframe.info()

X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = df.iloc[:, 4].values

# 80% training data, 20% testing data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

# Scale train and test data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler() #Here is the mistake, under scaler (Error code: 'Typo in the word scaler')
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Classify data
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Train and test result
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print(classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred))

# Scatter all the data points in a figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Financial Instrument Predicted Price')

# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)
poly.fit(X_poly, Y)
plt.plot(X, poly.fit_transform(X), color='red')
plt.show()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AAPL'
```

Comment: _What_ is telling you there is a typo? How does that prevent the code from running?

Comment: This is what I get: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AAPL'

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error; the comments space is **not** the place to do do.

Comment: Thanks, just made the change @desertnaut

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a typo, in the comments you said:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AAPL'

The error is clear actually, you have a string in your dataset, and trying to normalize/standardize your data. For most of the algorithms you need to encode your strings into integers. Since you did not provide any data sample, you can do, before splitting you can check your dataframe with

```
dataframe.info()
```

if it contains strings.

**Edit**: Check if your first row is supposed to be your header, then you can do the following:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('Test_Sample.csv', header = 0)
```

Comment: Most probably, it is just a header

Comment: fwiw, vscode/pycharm's dictionary might be saying there is a typo

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but I still have some errors unfortunately. I updated the code so you can take a look. All the data types I want to convert into float are objects, but for some reason it is still not working. Any suggestions?